# La diferencia entre «puerco» y «cerdo»

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, definiciones

Me gustaría saber cuál es la diferencia entre las dos palabras.

Para mí significan la misma cosa: "*pig*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desde el punto de vista del animal ambas palabras significan lo mismo "*Pig*" pero también tienen aún más significados.

En la RAE encuentras:

> [**Puerco**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UaBS0qP)
>
> 1. m. y f. cerdo (‖ mamífero).
> 2. m. y f. coloq. Persona desaliñada, sucia, que no tiene limpieza. U. t. c. adj.
> 3. m. y f. coloq. Persona grosera, sin cortesía ni crianza. U. t. c. adj.
> 4. m. y f. coloq. Persona ruin, interesada, venal. U. t. c. adj.
> 5. m. y f. Cineg. jabalí.
> 6. f. cochinilla.
> 7. adj. coloq. Dicho de una cosa: sucia (‖ que tiene manchas).

Las definiciones 2,3 y 4 hacen referencia a una persona sucia (de cuerpo, alma o mente) y la 7 habla de suciedad en general.

> [**Cerdo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8KHKmOx)
>
> 1. m. y f. Mamífero artiodáctilo del grupo de los suidos, de cuerpo grueso, cabeza y orejas grandes, hocico estrecho y patas cortas, que
>    se cría especialmente para aprovechar su cuerpo en la alimentación
>    humana. U. en m. ref. a la especie.
> 2. m. y f. coloq. puerco (‖ persona sucia). U. t. c. adj.
> 3. m. y f. coloq. puerco (‖ persona grosera). U. t. c. adj.
> 4. m. y f. coloq. puerco (‖ persona ruin). U. t. c. adj.

Igualmente las definiciones 2 a 4 hacen referencia a la suciedad.

En conclusión ambas palabras si significan lo mismo pero no únicamente *PIG*

Nota adicional: El animalito al que hacemos referencia además de **puerco** o **cerdo** también se le conoce como **marrano**, **chancho**, **cochino**, **lechón**. Todas estas palabras  también con el mismo significado coloquial que hace referencia a suciedad o a persona sucia.

Sin hacer una investigación exhaustiva y en mi opinión personal creo que es el animal que más nombres tiene.